# Is git stash pop command trusty? - might lead to lost of code?

Tags: git

I know it might sounds strange, but having going over and over with a really strange cases where my code was somehow deleted after performing the follow command:

```
git stash && git pull && git stash pop
```

I looked at my local history in webstorm (ignore the IDE's vendor, i'm running git from cmd):

[image: git_stash_pull_pop_auto_merge_issue]

The "External change" was due to me performing the command i mentioned above.

I checked with the other developer, if he did a correct pull on his side, and he did.

It happened to me a few times before, if anybody has encountered this issue with git or somebody that might know possible reasons for that?

Maybe git stash has a problem to identify large amount of changes?

I haven't found any related issues like this..

Small comment: again, yes, we checked the merging of the other developer.

Comment: You should not have lost anything.  The only possible explanation I can think of is that `git stash pop` somehow overwrote some of your work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - of course it somehow overwrote my local code, but i'm asking what my cause this?
The other developer didn't touch this part of the code.

So, can we trust git stash pop?

Comment: Keep in mind that when you pop/apply a stash, you are essentially taking a bunch of commits and applying them on top of your working directory and stage.  There is always the chance that something like this could happen.

Comment: Still, i didn't expect code to disappear - in the worst case, i would expect a conflict alert.

Comment: I suspect that the code in question here was being touched both by you and your colleague.  _Don't_ do that.  Try to divide your work so that you aren't both in the same method at the same time.

Comment: Same file, but not the same rows location.

Comment: When two developers step on each other's toes, this might happen.  Still, if you were working in different areas of the same file, I'm surprised.

Comment: deleted on your side or the other developer's side? Because you are talking about pull, but it is unclear who did *push*.

Comment: @VonC the other developer pushed it code, i did stash, then pulled his code , and then stash pop: the code at my side was deleted.

Comment: When you do your stash pop, what is your Git status? Are you on the right branch, correctly checked out?

Comment: @VonC yes, correct branch, code not committed yet (of course).